# How determine whether a MKS-sandbox is sparse or non-sparse from the command line?

Tags: mks, mks-integrity, sparse-checkout

how can I determine the sparse status of an MKS sandbox from the command line?

From the GUI, I can select a sandbox and open "Sandbox Information". If the check-box "Sparse" is set, the sandbox is sparse.

I like to determine this status from the command line in a script, to temporary set a sandbox to sparse, do some operations on it and then revert to it's original state.

The command `si sandboxinfo` does not display the sparse-status.

Answer (score 0):

Found it: The command `si sandboxinfo` **does** display the text

> sparse

for sparse-sandboxes and nothing for non-sparse sandboxes.